# Which java to install?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, java, jre

Application use java. When run script, it returns

./browser.sh
./browser.sh: 7: ./browser.sh: java: not found

I check java version:

```
java -v
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Which package should I install?

Comment: I wonder why it does not mention `openjdk-8-jre` (or `openjdk-8-jre-headless`), that would have been my choice.

Comment: @ByteCommander OpenJDK 8's final release was  on 3/18/2014, probably too late to be included in the main Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. It does seem as though it should be available through backports or something, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the [`default-jre`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/default-jre), that is `openjdk-7`.

This should be the more stable of all jre.

Comment: The applications written in Java require have installed both the **JRE** and **JDK**?

Comment: JRE means Java Runtime Environment, that is all needed to execute a Java application. JDK means Java Development Kit, is all needed to make Java applications. So if you only want to execute Java applications, JRE is ok.

Comment: I installed `default-jre` (I assumed its **JRE** only), but when I checked version it show it installed also JDK -- why?

_java -showversion_
`java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Its only its name of the project: 'openjdk'. This not mean that have been installed the JDK :)

Answer (score 3):

Very easy :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

After that, update package lists via:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install Oracle Java 8, run:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Change the number 8 to 6 (or 7) in the code to install Java 6 (or 7).

To set the default Java, run:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Also change number 8 to the Java version you want.

Finally check whether everyting is OK:

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install JDK on ubuntu is manually by downloading from oracle. You can refer following documentation for easy installation.

[6 Easy way to install Java JDK on Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question to add the relevant parts of the web site you linked to directly in your answer. Thanks!